# sectioning - \@startsection vertical spacing on top of page

Tags: spacing, sectioning

In the MWE below, the beforeskip argument to `\@startsection` (#4) seems to be ignored if `\section` occurs on top of a page. This is cool – because no big vertical space is needed here. 
However, what LaTeX does is bringing the baseline of the Section to the same 
level as a normal baseline (right column) although the font size is greater.

This can be seen here: 
[image]

What I need is to add a small vertical space of 3pt to the top line of the section-Box to move the baseline a bit down. In other words, what I'm looking at is to lower the baseline of the section by 3pt.

If I uncomment the `\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}` line in the MWE (see below), I get what I need. But I don't want to add this line each time by hand:

[image]

So, is there a way to modify `\@startsection` so that I can add some extra commands or spaces only in the case the section is ob top of the page?

(Just in case: It is really the design that the baseline of the section needs to be lowered by 3pt. The afterskip-Value (#5) equals to \baselineskip-3pt and is correct.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9.6pt}{13.7pt}\selectfont}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection%
{section}           % name
{1}                 % level
{6mm}               % indent
{-30.4pt}       % beforeskip
            % -30.4pt = -2\baselineskip+Grundlinienversatz
{10.7pt}        % afterskip
            % 10.7pt = \baselineskip + Grundlinienversatz
{\normalfont%
\bfseries%
\fontsize{11.5pt}{13.7pt}%
\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}%   Mediävalziffern
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=1.0}% Laufweite 10/1000 Geviert 
\selectfont%
\raggedright}%
} 
\makeatother

\parskip=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
%   \vspace*{-3\baselineskip}
    \section{Summary}

    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Section 2}

    \lipsum[2-7]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone on holidays here ...

So I found the following solution: I use `\raisebox{-3pt}` in order to lower the baseline of the section headline by 3pt ("Grundlinienversatz"). Inside the `\raisebox` I have to use a `\parbox` to enable for linebreaks in the headline. This enables for correct vertical positioning of the headline itself. Finally, vertical spacing after the headline has to be sorted out: `\prevdepth` has to be stored inside the `\parbox` and restored outside. To use all this together with `\@startsection`, I had to setup a new command `\my@sectbox` for all the mentioned operations. This can be passed to  `\@startsection` as argument #6.

This is the result:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{9.6pt}{13.7pt}\selectfont}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection%
{section}       % name
{1}             % level
{6mm}           % indent
{-27.4pt}       % beforeskip
                % -27.4pt = -2\baselineskip
{10.7pt}        % afterskip
                % 10.7pt = \baselineskip + 3pt Grundlinienversatz
{\my@sectbox}%
} 

\def\my@sectbox#1{%
    \noindent\raisebox{-3pt}{%
        \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
            % Setting up font size and style: 
            \normalfont%
            \bfseries%
            \fontsize{11.5pt}{13.7pt}%
            \addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}%   Mediävalziffern
            \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=1.0}% Laufweite 10/1000 Geviert 
            \selectfont%
            \raggedright%
            \strut#1%
            \xdef\rpd{\the\prevdepth}% saving \prevdepth inside box 
        }%
    }%

    \prevdepth=\rpd% restoring \prevdepth outside box (empty line above is mandatory)
    }
\makeatother

\parskip=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Summary}

    \lipsum[1]

    \section{Section two with a very long headline}

    \lipsum[2-7]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]